# .Net core 6 azure deploment issues

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I am new to learning .Net core. I have made a simple application and now I am trying to deploy it on Azure. I am getting some errors in my migration.

I have installed

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools => 6.0.4

I have run this command

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

I have these settings

[image]

when I click on TargetRuntime Portable I get this error under Entity framework migrations

[image]

Am I missing something?

Here is my appname.runtimeconfig.json

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the VS version? Do you have the migration dbcontext inside your published project?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Brando Zhang, Please make sure that while testing the .net core 6 project there is migration for database context in your published application  as below. And using [**`Visual studio 2022`**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) latest version.

[image]

After adding migration make sure that the email address and logout option is showing as below .

[image]

Once the above step is done make sure that while configuring Azure sql database you have *Expand Entity Framework Migrations and check Apply this migration on publish*.

[image]

*For complete setup how to create and publish .NET core 6 application to azure with Sql database by providing connection strings and secrets*, Please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0) .